# swift stream hls without m3u8 extension

Tags: ios, swift, stream, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I would like to ask you for help with HLS stream.
I would like to stream video in swift but problem is the format of downloaded file. I download m3u file from resource and there are links like:
http://192.168.2.100:8003/1:0:1:13F1:C87:3:EB0000:0:0:0:

Is it possible to play link like that or do I have to create an m3u8 file with link and then play it?

The stream is from enigma2 box.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Could somebody help me with playing the stream from enigma2 reciever?

Answer (score 0):

The file name doesn't matter as long as the server returns the correct Content-Type http header.